Spring Security file upload token validation
I've got a Spring Boot 3.0 webapp that is accessed via an Apache rewrite and uses Bearer Token (JWT) authentication.
The problem I'm facing is that the token lifetime is quite short (5 mins) and when doing large file uploads (that take longer than 5 mins) the token has expired by the time Spring tries to validate it.
Is there any way to convince Spring to validate the token when the request is first made, rather than waiting for the file to be transferred first?
I would have expected the FilterChain to kick off as soon as the request is made, but I'm only seeing it start once the file transfer is complete - starting with log statement "Securing POST /...".
Thanks
